# Accesing variables forma different py function Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, import

How could I see the amount of attributes and the list of variables within `file1` within `file2`. Is there a function or such that would allow me to see such a thing?

file1.py contents

```
value = 3
Random_numb = 6
lev = 8
```

file2.py contents

```
import file1
```

`file2`s Expected output:

```
List of variables:
value
Random_numb 
lev
```

Comment: if you want to see which variables are declared use `dir("file1.py")`, if you want the values as such, use `file1.value`

Answer (score 0):

```
for name_local in dir(file1):
    if not name_local.startswith('__'):
        print(f'{name_local}: {getattr(file1, name_local)}')
```

`dir(file1)` returns all attributes of that file but also some special attributes (like `__file__`) which are of no interest for you. So: Do only print the attributes that do not start with '__'

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.